# how to have subdomains point to different ports for different services with the same ip

Tags: dns, cloudflare, gitea, srv

I self-host a lot of my services, I have gitea and a website running on the same IP address.
for the longest time, I've just been adding my port at the end of the URL and it's been pretty decent for the most part, but I want to have git running on its own subdomain.

I've tried using namecheap dns and cloudflare dns and I make the SRV file and the A record but it still points back to the original website

Comment: Browsers do not honour DNS `SRV` records.

Comment: is their a better option then? does cname work?

Comment: You can't solve the problem at the DNS level... yet. The future is `SVCB` and `HTTPS` DNS records that start to be available in some browsers and DNS providers but it is not fully a standard yet. `CNAME` records only map a name to another name, there is no handling of ports.